# Does label mechanism provide auto-indexing features when using neo4j-java API?

Tags: neo4j

First of all, I bet that there is an answer on this question somewhere in docs, but since 'Manual: Labels and Indexes' link [here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels) gives me 404 error, I'm going to ask you anyway.

1. Is it possible to create an index on some label and specify it as an automatic one (just like legacy indexes I'm currently using, but for labels)?
2. If someone from neo4j team is reading this post, please let me know if I'm looking for the documentation in the right place, 'cause I can't find anything more or less informative on labels and indexes (except a couple of posts in Michael Hunger's blog and, maybe, some presentations, what is obviously not enough).
3. This is a more technical one: is it possible to find an item in the index by the regex? Suppose I have node with property `'n' -> '/a/b/c'`, and another node `'n' -> '/a/*/c`. Can I somehow match them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't work for Neo4j but I'll answer anyway.

1. All label indexing is automatic. Once you've created the index it maintains itself, possibly with minimal delay.
2. The manual for the last stable release can always be found [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/index.html). The chapter on indexing for the embedded Java API is [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html).
3. You cannot use regexp with label indices yet. It's said to be on the agenda, along with index support for array lookups, i.e. what in Cypher would be

   `MATCH (a:MyLabel) WHERE a.value IN ['val1', 'val2']`

Comment: It's not that page itself that returns 404, but the 'Manual: Indexes and Labels' link on that page. Thank you for your answer anyway, it resolves most of the questions.

Comment: I see, yes that link does seem to be broken. It's probably from before 2.0 was released and could do with an update.